# Showing unique prime factorization in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Suppose I have the symbols $\{\neg, \rightarrow, =, <,\cdot, \leftrightarrow,\land, \lor \}$ and functions $Div(x,y)$ ($x$ divides $y$), $Prime(x)$ true if $x$ is a prime, and domain $\mathbb{N}$. How can I construct a formula that expresses the fact that every number greater than 0 has unique prime factorization?

My thought requires the ability to have ellipses, to show for example for a number $k$ it is that $\exists a_1,\ldots,a_k$ such that $a_1^{n_1}\cdots a_{j}^{n_j}= k$ for $j \leq k$. For example, $4 = 2^2$.

Something like this, I don't know.

How can I construct such a formula?

Comment: Can you even express $a=b\cdot c$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I believe that you can in the following way, $Div(b,a)\wedge Div(c,a)\wedge((Div(b,d)\wedge Div(c,d))\implies a\leq d)$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I forgot multiplication. You CAN use it :)

Comment: When you say you have the domain $\mathbb{N}$, do you have some sort of induction or recursion?

Comment: By the way $Prime(x)$ is writable as $Div(x,y)$ as follows, $Prime(x)=Div(y,x)\implies (x=y)\vee (x=1)$, at least if you have the constant $1$, and you know that $\forall x,Div(1,x)$.

Comment: @BabyDragon I just mean that when I say $\forall x$ I mean for all integers greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: I've managed to come up with this, but I feel it should be easier:
$$\forall n.\exists k.\exists x_1.\ldots.\exists x_k.\exists m_1.\ldots.m_k( ArePrime(x_1,\ldots,x_k) \land (n = x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_k^{m_k}) ) $$
(where $ArePrime$ is pretty self-explanatory and I define it)

Comment: @BabyDragon That does not work for $4=2\cdot 2$.

Comment: @snario: Unfortunately, that's second order logic, since you're quantifying over how many quantifiers to use. I don't think you can even express the notion of "factorization" within your language. The usual theory of natural numbers has to take great advantage of +, *, and induction to be able to work natively with things like lists of numbers.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That is true, I was perhaps being too optimistic. Snario, You formulas have an implicit use of a variable $k$. The problem is that the legnth of prime factorizations gets arbitrarily large.

Comment: Yeah this is my problem - I suppose I should just describe the limits in first-order logic for this problem. (Also in my last answer I forgot to address unique factorization). I should add that this is a challenge problem for an assignment so I shouldn't give out too much information.

Comment: $Div(x,y)$ is not a function, as you claim.

Comment: Note also that you can define $Div$, by $Div(x,y)$ iff $\exists t\,(t\cdot x=y)$. $Prime$ is also definable, so you do not need either predicate. Anyway: You cannot write the statement you want in first order logic, precisely because you do not have "ellipses". If you tell us what results you already know, it may be easier to suggest a proof.

Comment: The course I'm taking is currently studying first order logic, and this is an "enrichment" problem, probably to show me the problems with first order logic, and as an introduction to second order logic. The predicates $Div$ and $IsPrime$ were previous questions on the assignment, I just stated them here for convenience. I feel as though the question in my context has been answered, however should someone wish to provide a proof using second order logic that would be appreciated. I've said more or less every result we have thus far in the question statement

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is that there is no *a priori* bound on the number of factors. So, to express the fundamental theorem of arithmetic in a first-order theory such as Peano arithmetic, you first need to show that the theory is able to express the idea of quantifying over finite sequences. The machinery to do this is well understood; one commonly used method is the [$\beta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del's_%CE%B2_function) introduced by Kurt Gödel.

The general idea is that the final sentence will say "for every $n > 1$ there is a finite sequence $\sigma$ such that (1) each number appearing in $\sigma$ is prime, and (2) $n$ is the product of the numbers appearing in $\sigma$."

Answer (score 1):

Let us first define $\text{Prime}(n)$ to be an expression that is true iff $n$ is prime:

$$ \text{Prime}(n) \stackrel{\text{def}}{⟺} ∀x∀y\Big[ (x×y=n) ⟶ (1<n<x+y) \Big] $$

This works because the only pair factors of $n$ who's sum is greater than $n$ is $1$ and $n$ itself.

Now let us define $d$ divides $n$ ($d|n$):

$$ d|n \stackrel{\text{def}}{⟺} ∃x \big[d×x=n\big]$$

Now note that a number is either $0$, $1$, prime, or a composite number (divisible by a prime):

$$ ∀x\Big[(x<0)∨\text{Prime}(x) ∨ ∃y∃z\big[(y×z=x)∧\text{Prime}(y)\big]\Big] $$

So now we know that every composite number $x$ has a prime factor $y$ and another factor $z$. If $z$ in a prime number, $x$ is the product of 2 prime numbers.

Sorry, I'm not entirely sure where to go from here, but I thought I'd post this anyway in case it's any use to you. Maybe I'll come back and edit it later.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $ \text{Prime}(n) \stackrel{\text{def}}{⟺} ∀x∀y\Big[ (x×y=n) ⟶ (1<\color{red}{n}<x+y) \Big] $ instead of $\color{red}{p}$?